# F# Simple Tree evaluation

Tags: f#

I'm currently trying to learn the idiomatic way to write F# code. The code simulates a basic calculator with only binary plus, minus and unary minus.

I'd like to know if there is a better way to group union cases than the way I did it. Should the `Add/Sub/MinusExpression` be cases in the Expression union? Is there a better way to write the `eval` function?

```
type Expression =
    | BinExpression of BinExpression
    | UnExpression  of UnExpression
    | IntExpression of int

and BinExpression =
    | AddExpression of Expression * Expression
    | SubExpression of Expression * Expression

and UnExpression =
    | MinusExpression of Expression

let rec eval tree =
    let evalBin tree =
        match tree with
        | AddExpression(e1, e2) -> (eval e1) + (eval e2)
        | SubExpression(e1, e2) -> (eval e1) - (eval e2)

    let evalUn tree =
        match tree with
        | MinusExpression(v) -> -(eval v)

    match tree with
    | BinExpression(e) -> evalBin e
    | UnExpression(e)  -> evalUn e
    | IntExpression(v) -> v
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple domain like that, wouldn't it be simpler to define the data like this?

```
type Expression =
| IntExpr of int
| AddExpr of Expression * Expression
| SubtractExpr of Expression * Expression
| NegationExpr of Expression
```

This would mean that you can implement the `eval` function like this:

```
let rec eval = function
| IntExpr i -> i
| AddExpr (x, y) -> eval x + eval y
| SubtractExpr (x, y) -> eval x - eval y
| NegationExpr x -> -(eval x)
```

Here are some FSI examples:

```
> let x1 = IntExpr 42 |> eval;;    
val x1 : int = 42

> let x2 = AddExpr (IntExpr 1, IntExpr 32) |> eval;;    
val x2 : int = 33

> let x3 = NegationExpr (SubtractExpr (NegationExpr (IntExpr 3), (AddExpr (IntExpr 4, IntExpr 7)))) |> eval;;    
val x3 : int = 14
```

Comment: Is that still viable if I get more cases like Mul/Div/Mod/And/Or/etc? And coming from C# the urge to group these in more specific unions is still there, I'm mostly wondering if this is just me trying to apply C# to F# or if this is the "right" way to do it in F#?

Comment: That *'etc'* hides the answer to that question. How much more do you need to add? What does the complex structure afford? In general, I often find the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020) helpful - in this case, *Flat is better than nested*. My inclination would be to keep it flat until I can clearly see the benefit of introducing a more nested model.

Comment: I was thinking about the scale of a parse tree for a programming language but the only thing a more complex structure would gain in that case is the ability to fine grain the `match` statements on the other hand that would make it more readable. What I take away from this is a _if you can give an good argument for it may be a good idea_.

Comment: @prydain Well, yes... *It depends*... :$